# How to stop page refresh when changing url by history.replacestate in angularjs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug

I'm updating my page URL from on a span click in my angularjs+jade+nodejs application.
http://192.xxx.0.xxx:7071/page-1/blog
to
http://192.xxx.0.xxx:7071/page-2/blog

I am using history.replaceState to change.
But as the function execute the page gets automatically refreshed.
I want to stop the reload using replaceState. Is there any other solution available?

If I write history.replacestate(null, null, '/page-2/blog') in console of browser it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to "reloadOnSearch: false" .

If you add this in your angularJS module you can't disable the refresh

[reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route with true, or false if you don't want to refresh .